# specify return type for inline functions with flow

Tags: flowtype

I have the following functions:

```
const safeNull = fn => (txt: string): string => (isNil(txt) ? '' : fn(txt));

export const stripSpaces: Function = safeNull(txt => txt.replace(/\s/g, ''));

export const safeTrim: Function = safeNull(txt => txt.trim());
```

How do I say that `stripSpaces` and `safeTrim` return strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `safeNull` function is typed to return a function that returns a string.
So all you have to do is remove those `Function` types from `stripSpaces` and `safeTrim`.
Flow will infer that they return strings, because of `safeNull` return type.

```
const safeNull = fn => (txt: string): string => (isNil(txt) ? '' : fn(txt));

export const stripSpaces = safeNull(txt => txt.replace(/\s/g, ''));

export const safeTrim = safeNull(txt => txt.trim());
```

You could also explicitly define their types, if you prefer, like so:

```
const safeNull = fn => (txt: string): string => (isNil(txt) ? '' : fn(txt));

export const stripSpaces: string => string = safeNull(txt => txt.replace(/\s/g, ''));

export const safeTrim: string => string = safeNull(txt => txt.trim());
```